# How did Data get Spot?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data

[image]

So how did Data get his cat, Spot? Did Data pick him up on Earth or something?

Comment: +1, I knew there was a question I wanted to aks but had forgotten to!

Comment: I'm surprised it's not covered there, but I think the [Memory Alpha article about spot](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spot) is still relevant.

Comment: At the local space SPCA.

Comment: NO!  Obviously Data built him while practicing building positronic brains before Lal.  And this also explains why Spot changed breeds and couldn't relate to Geordi.

Comment: Well the Enterprise has an Arboretum on board, why not a pet shelter too?

Comment: Watching 'Datas Day' now (again) and thought I must have fallen asleep when he got spot, so here I am asking "where did Data get Spot from" and.......no answer. I personally think he inherited Spot from a crewman who could no longer care for him.

Comment: I'm gonna go with holodeck, transporter or replicator failure, for $400 Alex.

Comment: There's a particular episode Spot is suspiciously missing from: Measure of a Man.  Data accounts for every one of his most personal belongings, but one thing that never gets accounted for, or brought up in his trail as a sentient being, is his ownership of a cat.  Nor, in fact, does it get brought up when he's abducted in "The Most Toys".

Comment: @Jared The A in SPCA refers to an earth country that doesn't exist in star trek. If anything it would be SPCF: society for prevention of cruelty to federations.

Comment: More correctly, shouldn't the question be "How did Spot choose Data"?

Comment: @DarthEgregious The A in SPCA stands for Animals. You may be think of the ASPCA, where the *other* A stands for American.

Comment: "Computer: cat, domestic, orange".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Strange though it may sound, there does not appear to be any explanation, canonical or otherwise, for Spot's appearance (let alone for changes of breed or gender, as mentioned in the Memory Alpha article referenced in the comments above). One day, ("Data's Day", to be precise :-) ), we just suddenly discovered that Data had a cat, and apparently had had one for some time.

For all we know, Spot predates Data's duty aboard *Enterprise*-D. Beyond that, we can speculate endlessly -- she might have been Data's own acquisition or that of another crew member who passed away or discovered they were allergic or otherwise couldn't care for her any more, for example.

We simply don't know, and, to judge from the Memory Beta article (which tracks non-canon references), no author has chosen to speculate.

Comment: I would have expected him to worry about Data when the Enterprise was separated in *Encounter at Farpoint*. I'd think he didn't have Spot back then.

Comment: Cat or no cat, Data was an on-duty officer in a time of crisis. He would no more spend time openly dwelling on his cat's well being than another officer would about his wife or children; especially this early in Data's exploration of emotion.

Comment: Interesting timing on this post.  I just watched "Data's Day" last night, in my quest to re-watch the entire season, and was thinking of asking this same question.  If we presume Data's ownership of Spot pre-dated his service aboard the Enterprise, that would leave some plot holes where Spot should have appeared previous to "Data's Day".  Additionally, it seems Spot has changed breeds at least once since her first appearance as well.

Comment: You know cats...maybe it played with the replicator, tail hit the wrong button, fur got recolored,...it happens.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim When things go into a replicator, they tend to be put through a reclamation process back to the base components for reuse.  The more likely possibility is that the cat strolled into a transporter beam with another cat that had some issues a la "Tuvix" and caused a combination of their DNA in the resulting mixup.

Comment: @Iszi It's not uncommon to name a new cat after its predecessor. So maybe Data did not take that good care of Spot I :-/

Comment: He definitely doesn't predate Data's duties aboard Enterprise D - if that were the case, he certainly would've been accounted for or at least mentioned during his trail as a sentient being in "Measure of a Man".

Comment: Oooo! Good point. I hadn't thought of that...

Answer (score 4):

Data's Day happens shortly after Data meets Dr. Soong, and it is clear after he returns to the enterprise that he has brought back some of Soong's belongings. My theory is that Spot actually belonged to his father and so he inherited her.

Comment: This is a fan-theory. It's kinda interesting but not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: It's as valid as the other Theories. I like it.

Answer (score 4):

Spot does look a lot like Tasha Yar's cat.  Given that she and Data "hooked up" during the episode '[The Naked Now](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now_%28episode%29)', perhaps he inherited her cat when she died.

Comment: The TNG Novel Survivors indicated that her cat was killed on-planet before she left to join the Federation. Obviously the novels aren't canon but there's no special reason to assume it's incorrect.

Comment: Cannon or not, this is the answer I choose to believe. (assuming Yar *did* have a cat on TNG?)

Answer (score 2):

It was mentioned somewhere (wish to GOD I could recall where) that the cat from "Data's Day' had contracted feline leukemia and passed away rather suddenly, and that a second cat had been replaced due to attacking a castmember (I do believe it was Michael Dorn!) when seeing him in costume.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: It is a real world answer instead of a an in universe answer.  The question seems to be for a real world answer.