# Where/how did Data get Spot the cat?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Cmdr. Data had a pet cat named Spot.

Where/how did he get it?

Memory Alpha's [Spot](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spot) explains that there were many cats on the *Enterprise*-D, so it probably wasn't produced in a replicator.

Did Data adopt a kitten from a litter born on the *Enterprise* and raise it, or adopt it from the *Enterprise* Animal Shelter, or...?

Comment: I didn’t think it was possible to produce living matter in the replicators anyway. Only inanimate stuff like food or objects.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan ya that was (dry) humor

Comment: Duplicate of [How did Data get Spot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15663/how-did-data-get-spot)